# Database combine two queries into one

Tags: mysql, select, combinations

I have table that has 2 fields userId and ebayitemId. Following is table from database:

```
userId     | ebayitemId
12         | 1
12         | 2
12         | 3
12         | 4
```

In my situation, the client makes request  with `ebayitemId` to see what other items are listed with this user.( `ebayitemId` is unique ). So far I am using two query to select all items listed by the user. First query is

```
SELECT userId WHERE ebayitemId = '1'
```

This query gets me USERID FOR THAT EBAYITEMID.

The second query is

```
SELECT ebayitemId WHERE userId = '$userid'
```

This gives me ebayitemId 1,2,3 and 4.

My question: Is there a way to combine these two queries into one query to get above result since only one table is involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query :

```
SELECT iu.ebayitemId
FROM t_items AS iu
INNER JOIN t_items AS ii ON (iu.userId=ii.userId)
WHERE (ii.ebayitemId= $item )
```

and if you don't want the first item to be selected :

```
SELECT iu.ebayitemId
FROM t_items AS iu
INNER JOIN t_items AS ii ON (iu.userId=ii.userId)
WHERE (ii.ebayitemId= $item )
AND (iu.ebayitemId<>ii.ebayitemId)
```

Note : an IN statement would be less optimized.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with

```
SELECT ebayitemId from table WHERE userId in (SELECT userId from table WHERE ebayitemId = '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Naively:

```
SELECT ebayitemId
FROM yourtable
WHERE userId IN (
    SELECT userId
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE ebayitemId = '1'
)
```

Note there are other ways to skin this cat with joins etc.